# Java - Colouring image

Tags: java, image, colors, bufferedimage, multiplication

I've tried to create colored gray image with given colour but I always failed. I know I have to use BufferedImage and load all pixels of source image into array, but I don't know how to work with color value, so there always were some weird colors after multiplying source color and given color (for the record I've got code to get int of color).

Thanks for any help.

e.g. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17664230/ruka.png

Comment: Do you mean you want the background of the image to change color?  If that's the case you have to take a look at transparency.

Comment: Nope. I want the gray image to change color like this http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17664230/ruka.png

Comment: Are you using an ImageFilter anywhere? That's what has worked for me in the past. In fact what code ***are*** you currently trying to use?

Comment: I am using this code for retrieving int color http://pastebin.com/YRYmLrBz

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change image gray channel (white-black) to (some_color-black) ?

```
public void recolor(BufferedImage source, BufferedImage destination, int color) {
    WritableRaster destinationRaster = destination.getRaster();
    Raster sourceRaster = source.getRaster();
    //red, green, blue
    int channels = new int[]{color & 0xFF0000, color & 0xFF00, color & 0xFF};

    for (int channel=0; channel<3; channel++){
        for (int y=0; y<sourceRaster.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x=0; x<rangeSlicer.getWidth(); x++) {
                pixel = sourceRaster.getSample(x, y, channel);
                pixel = Math.round((double)pixel/255.0 * channels[channel]);
                destinationRaster.setSample(x, y, channel, pixel);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure if this compiles, but idea is that. For more effective program check [RescaleOp](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/RescaleOp.html).

Comment: No, simply I just want colorize with given color sprite like is one of these on spritesheet: http://bit.ly/vcHsdl

Comment: I tried that, but it's not working. It changes color but not correctly. I'd prefer BufferedImage methods like getRGB and setRGB. I just need to know what to do with colours, merge? Multiply? Addition them?

Comment: getRGB returns a integer value that represents 4 channels [alpha,reg,green,blue]. All channels are values in range 0-255. (Your input image is gray-scale so that means red, green and blue channels are the same value in range 0-255). To get colorized result you need to multiply every channel separately with a given color same channel and divide by 255. Input image channels will be used as intensity level for color channels you use. Leave alpha channel unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I would define some `alpha = 0.2` and do:

```
given gray #777777
make redder with: 
                  new red = 77 * (1.0 + alpha)
                  new green = blue = 77 * (1.0 - alpha)
```

Actually, you have to be careful and make sure to truncate (1 + alpha) and (1 - alpha) such that you only use values between 0 and 1.0.
Use Math.min(0.0, 1.0 - alpha) instead of (1.0 - alpha) and Math.max(1.0, 1.0 + alpha) instead of (1.0 + alpha).

With this formula, if you are given black (#000000), it stays black. If you are given white (#FFFFFF), it ends up pink (#FFCCCC).  If you set alpha = 1.0, white would end up pure red (#FF0000).

You could come up with different color scaling formulas, but I guess you should make sure that your transformation always keeps black as pure black.